# Xamly determine if a ListBox.Items.Count > 0

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

Is there a way **in XAML** to determine if the ListBox has data?

I wanna set its IsVisibile property to false if no data.

Comment: +1 for coining the term "xamly".

Comment: Have you got any better term?...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The ListBox contains a [HasItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.hasitems.aspx) property you can bind to. So you can just do this:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />
...
<ListBox 
    Visibility="{Binding HasItems, 
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
      Converter=BooleanToVisibility}" />
```

Or as a Trigger so you don't need the converter:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

I haven't tested the bindings so there might be some typos but you should get the idea.

Comment: +1 - this is a nice solution, and is cleaner than the trigger for the "zero items" situation. The trigger is useful if you want other behaviour or if you want to trigger something for a specific count of items.

Comment: Matt, you're right, I will use the HasItem property but with a trigger as you suggested.

Comment: and you know what' I think the HasItems is even a DependencyProperty!

Comment: Agreed, this looks like the nicest answer. My background in Silverlight meant I hadn't seen RelativeSource before, and HasItems is clearly nicer than Items.Count.

Comment: Yes, HasItems is a DependencyProperty. You can bind to it and everything will update when the property changes. I don't think IEnumerable.Count will do that.

Comment: Don't know why, but HasItems did not work for me: items.count was above zero, but HasItems was still false.

Comment: @Zéiksz Were you binding to a collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged? If not then the control is never informed that items were added/removed from the collection.

Answer (score 14):

Do it in a trigger and you won't need a ValueConverter:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
          Binding="Items.Count, {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
          Value="0">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

So that shows the ListBox by default, but if Items.Count is ever 0, the ListBox is hidden.

Comment: Take a look at Bryan Anderson's post, he suggests to use the HasItems property of the listbox itself, which would be better than dig into the collection count.
Matt's triggerring way is better and shorter than a conveter tho.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make this work using a ValueConverter and normal binding.

Set Visibility to be:

```
Visibility = "{Binding myListbox.Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
```

Then set up your converter to return Visibility.Collapsed etc based on the value of the count.

Comment: `ItemCollection.Count` is not a dependency property and the binding will not get updated when the number of items in the collection changes.

Comment: <ListBox Visibility="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource EmptyListVisibilityConverter}}"/>

Comment: Martin, you seem to be right, but the above code works for me.
probably the collection changed event refreshed the visibilty property as well.

Comment: I would expect a pure 'xamly' item but I assume there is no other way without using a converter.
I think wpf should have builtin conditional converters as boolean terms, boolean switch; or and > < = etc. operators etc.

Comment: @Martin, take a look on Bryan Anderson's response.