# Visibility against the collection of items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, imultivalueconverter

I have dropdown and Grid. in the grid column there is hyperlink.If the Dropdown collection contains 1 item then the dropdown should be  invisible.I meean need a logic to bind Visibility against the collection of items.

Here is the XAML for one Hyperlink in the GRid.

```
   <!--Associate-->
                    <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 0, 0">                                    
                        <TextBlock.Visibility>                                           
                                 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource courseListVisibilityConverter}"
                                                     ConverterParameter="Associate">
                                          <Binding Path="IsCourseAssocited"
                                                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DPA2:TakenCoursesNotApplied}}" />
                                            <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                       </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Visibility>

                        <Hyperlink DataContext="{Binding}"
                                   Name="Associate"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}}, Path=IsVisible}"
                                    Click="Associate_Click">
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        Text="Associate" />
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>

 public class CourseListVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value[0] == null || value[1] == null) return Visibility.Collapsed;
        bool IsEditMode = value[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue ? false : (bool)value[0];

        if (value[1].GetType() == typeof(Course))
        {
            Course course = value[1] as Course;
            if (course == null) return string.Empty;

            //Visibility retVal = Visibility.Visible;
            switch (parameter.ToString())
            {
                case "CodeLink":
                    if (!IsEditMode) return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (course.HideOptions) return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (course.IsInElectivePool &&
                        course.IsManualAdd) return Visibility.Visible;
                    if (!course.IsInElectivePool &&
                            !course.IsWaived) return Visibility.Visible;

                    if (course.IsInElectivePool &&
                        course.FulFillmentId != 0 &&
                        course.FulFillmentId != -1 &&
                        !course.IsWaived) return Visibility.Visible;

                    return Visibility.Collapsed;

                case "CodeNoLink":
                    if (!IsEditMode) return Visibility.Visible;
                    if (course.HideOptions) return Visibility.Visible;

                    if (course.IsInElectivePool &&
                        course.IsManualAdd) return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (!course.IsInElectivePool &&
                          !course.IsWaived) return Visibility.Collapsed;

                    if (course.IsInElectivePool &&
                        course.FulFillmentId != 0 &&
                        course.FulFillmentId != -1 &&
                        !course.IsWaived) return Visibility.Collapsed;

                    return Visibility.Visible;

                case "Waive":
                    if (course.HideOptions) return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (IsEditMode &&
                        !course.IsWaived &&
                         !(course.RetakenFlag == RetakeFlagType.RetakeOfCourse) &&
                        !course.IsInElectivePool) return Visibility.Visible;
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;

                case "UndoWaive":
                    if (course.HideOptions) return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (IsEditMode && course.IsWaived &&
                          !(course.RetakenFlag == RetakeFlagType.RetakeOfCourse) &&
                        !course.IsInElectivePool) return Visibility.Visible;
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;

                case "UndoAdd":
                    if (course.HideOptions) return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (IsEditMode && course.IsManualAdd &&
                        (!(course.RetakenFlag == RetakeFlagType.RetakeOfCourse) &&
                         !course.IsInElectivePool)) return Visibility.Visible;
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                case "Associate":
                    if (course.HideOptions) return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (IsEditMode && course.IsCourseAssocited)
                        return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    else if (IsEditMode &&
                        ((course.Status.ToUpper() == "COMPLETE" || course.Status.ToUpper() == "DROPPED")))
                    {
                        return Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                //case "UnAssociate":
                //    if (course.HideOptions) return Visibility.Collapsed;
                //    if (IsEditMode && (course.IsCourseAssocited))

                //    {
                //        return Visibility.Visible;
                //    }
                //    else
                //    {
                //        return Visibility.Collapsed;
                //    }
                case "FullFillRequirement":
                    if (course.HideOptions) return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (IsEditMode &&
                        ((course.Status.ToUpper() == "FUTURE")))
                    {
                        return Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                default:
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        else if (value[1].GetType() == typeof(ElectivePool))
        {
            ElectivePool electivePool = value[1] as ElectivePool;
            if (electivePool == null) return string.Empty;

            switch (parameter.ToString())
            {
                case "Waive":

                    if (IsEditMode &&
                        !electivePool.IsWaived) return Visibility.Visible;
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;

                case "UndoWaive":
                    if (IsEditMode &&
                        electivePool.IsWaived) return Visibility.Visible;
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could bind visibility to the HasItems property and use [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx)

```
Visibility="{Binding HasItems,ElementName=ELementName,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}"
```

[or do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905881/wpf-treeviewitem-toggle-button-visibility) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384451/xamly-determine-if-a-listbox-items-count-0)

Comment: This works like a charm, but only thing is, immediately if I remove the items from the list the visibility of the textBlock should be visible again, that's not happening,

Answer (score 1):

1. IsVisible is not a property of TextBlock, you need to use [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx) property;
2. `RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DPA2:TakenCoursesNotApplied}}"` - You can't use `FindAncestor` statement unless your `DPA2:TakenCoursesNotApplied` type is control that is in visual tree above your TextBlock.

Perhaps you need some value converter that accepts count of elements in your collection and returns `Visibility.Collapsed` if count == 1.

Comment: ,can we use A collection which is in Presentation model in the converter.

Comment: 2.Can we use property which is poplated in the PresentationModel, in the converter.I mean to say In model i check the collection count and update boolena property.Can i use the same property in the Converter calss.

Comment: Yes, you can use your boolean property with [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx), but not forget to use PropertyChanged notification. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) is example.

Comment: You can use something like `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionOfMyItems}" Visibility="{Binding Path=CollectionContainsMoreThanOneElement, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />` where "CollectionContainsMoreThanOneElement" is your boolean property and 
booleanToVisibilityConverter is instance of [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).

Comment: This visibility will work for the ComoboBox.But i need the visibility of Hyperlink.I ahave added the Converter code.but can i aceess the model property in the converter.so that i can add a extra check here.

Comment: Yes, and you don't need MultiValueConverter, you can use simple IValueConverter implementation in your CourseListVisibilityConverter and use this converter for TextBlock Visivility like this: `<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource courseListVisibilityConverter}}" />` then you will have in your converter whole your PresentationModel and you'll can add any extra checks that you need in your CourseListVisibilityConverter.